# Get average for only a certain date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In a database with hourly trade prices for the last ten years, the following query will group prices by day, produce a daily average price, and return the average price for every day in the DB:

```
Trade.average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date)")
```

But, this will return an excessively large response, and I only need to get average prices for the last 7 days.  What can I add to this query to only perform the averaging for the last 7 days of data as given in the `date` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Trade.where('date >= ?', 7.days.ago).average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date)")
```

Comment: Thank you Mischa!  Works perfectly.  I have been trying to do this for an hour, but chaining them with incorrect syntax.  You've made a difference.  Cheers :)